# Careers 2.0 email subject lines should include applicant name

Tags: feature-request, jobs, email

Without the applicant name all the message updates from Careers 2.0 have the same subject. Gmail then groups all these emails together which is super annoying to find the coherent conversation with the applicant.

Comment: Hey at least you're getting responses! :(

Comment: Agreed! I ran a search recently and was highly communicative with the applicants, and 40 applicants with 3-5 messages each on average made for some long gmail threads. I understand the point is to interact *within the system* (which I did), but reviewing the conversation (which I also did) via email was difficult.